# How to know a downloaded database file is secure?

Tags: security, ms-access, type-conversion

maybe it's two questions but maybe someone has already faced with my issue exactly, and just knows ONE precise answer during this conversion target described below. I have downloaded an empty .mdb access file from [this site](http://www.dugeo.com/), which apparently must be blank to do my *.sql to .mdb* conversion using sql server import&export wizard; I found no threat using HitmanPro from the downloaded .mdb file, but it is 3.5Mg !! and it's still suspicious for me how a blank database file could be 3mg?! (I tried to use copy a trusted .mdb file existing in my laptop, I deleted the tables inside in order to make it blank but apparently there must be other configurations to make it a convertible .mdb file into .sql or vice versa; I faced with these errors during the export of SQL Server:

> *Error 0xc02020a1* , *Error 0xc020902a*, *Error 0xc0202092*, *Error 0xc0047038*

Although I can insist and follows those errors in this forum and stackoverflow, but I just want faster way, because that website mentioned above demonstrates conversion using SQL Server export wizard, and has put that .mdb file as a requirement [in this discription](http://help.dugeo.com/m/faq/l/176948-exporting-sql-database-to-access)

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking and how you got those errors.

Comment: When I want to convert a SQL file using "SQL Server Import&Export Wizard" to a .mdb Access file, I should select an empty ,mdb file to copy converted contents into it, I face with those errors.

Comment: And what is a "Mg"? Did you mean MB (Mega bytes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a basic misunderstanding of what a blank database file is. In our parlance, that just means that there's no user data in the file. It doesn't mean that the file is zero bytes in size.

If you create a new empty database using Microsoft Access today, you'll find that it is a certain size, even though there's nothing in it. No tables, queries, etc.

However, under the covers, the file itself contains information to make it understood by Microsoft Access. This is called the file format. No file formats for complex applications start off at zero bytes. You'll find exactly the same case with a Word or Excel document.

What I suspect is that your downloaded file contains empty database structures. This is the same as a "blank" Excel file containing, say, ten worksheets that are formatted with headers, but no data. It will also be a suspicious size if you're unfamiliar with the file format.

Don't delete what's in the file you downloaded. See if it works.

I hope that helps your understanding better.

Comment: ! thanks for your answer, but of course I know it's not zero byte! but not that much as 3Mg! (for example the file which I deleted the data inside tables and queries, it became only 350kb. But, in any case I used McAfee database security scanner, and It was safe. Thanks again in anyway